# App suddenly will not run on device

Tags: xcode

I have been running an app on my ipod that I've been developing for a while now and all of a sudden it won't run.  I haven't changed xcode or macos; I've deleted the derived data folder; I've restarted the device, computer and xcode and cleaned.

The error I'm getting is: "could not start debugserver on MyDevice when trying to launch My.app"

My provisioning profile and device are green.  I can't understand what I could possibly have changed.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Restart Xcode and the device and you should be fine.

Comment: As I stated, I have restarted xcode, I have restarted the device, I have restarted the computer - to no avail.  I have also cleaned, deleted the app from the ipod.

Comment: I didn't need to restart my device. Just restaring Xcode worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

just CMD+shift+K, clean you project. when it's done, it should be work. at least for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting the installed application from your phone. That worked for me as none of the above methods did.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while I was testing iOS beta. I updated iOS version on device and I had to restart xcode and then reconnect to

Answer (score 0):

1. Restart xcode.
2. Unplug iPhone/iPad from usb cable (If connected with usb cable).
3. Turn off wifi and connect again (If you are using wifi debug).
4. Clean project.
5. Run your app again.