# Could not start debugserver on “D’s iPhone” when trying to launch “Name of app”

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging

I'm working on an iOS app, written in Swift. I try to run it on my iPhone 6S as a testing device but I get this error and I cannot figure out how to get around it:

`Could not start debugserver on “D’s iPhone” when trying to launch “Name of app”`

MacOS X is 10.13.3, Xcode 9.2 (since it's the stable version, not beta) and my iPhone runs 11.2.6 version

I tried restarting my phone, reconnecting the USB, connect via network. Nothing. It installs the app but it doesn't run it.

Comment: Have you fully quit and reopened Xcode?

Comment: Did you try to restart XCode too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831395/app-suddenly-will-not-run-on-device

Comment: Oh, I forgot to restart Xcode. That worked actually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App suddenly will not run on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831395/app-suddenly-will-not-run-on-device)

Answer (score 7):

The answer was to restart Xcode.